# Multiple Definitions of... | C++

Tags: c++, linker, object-files

This is a somewhat theoretical question...

I have been reading up on linking object files. Now I get error messages about multiple definitions of some functions. I believe to have identified the issue as follows:

- I have two separate header files A and B.
- Both headers access the same header H.
- From A and B I have compiled object files AO and BO.
- When I try to compile a cpp-File M, that includes A and B by linking AO and BO to M, I get error messages about multiple definitions.
- The function(s) that the error message(s) are about are located in H.

I assume the issue is, that in both AO and BO is somehow references or compiled code to/ from H, so that it appears twice when I link AO ad BO when compiling M. Have I recognized the issue correctly, or am I likely missing something ele?

And if so, how do you avoid or work around such issue?

Edit: I said I compiled header files. Sorry, that was sloppy way to say it. I compiled the cpp files with the implementations of the class methods in the header files A and B.

Comment: Do you have full functions (ie. including the actual code within `{}` in H? If yes, that shouldn´t be there, and that´s the problem.

Comment: I suggest you read about ODR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Comment: You should probably post your code, it's hard to understand what you have done that resulted in the MD errors. For one thing you say you compiled header files, you don't want to do that.

Comment: @lo tolmencre: "From A and B I have compiled object files AO and BO" - what does this mean? You said that  and B are *header* files. How do you compile header files into object files???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never compile `.h` (header) files. A *header file* is a C++ source file that is meant to be included in other C++ source files via an `#include` directive.

The only files you should be compiling are `.cpp` files, which are often referred to as *implementation files*.

It is also important that you not include function definitions in your header files. Each function definition must only be compiled once, and thus must be coded into exactly one implementation file. Header files should only contain:

- forward declarations
- macros
- other `#include`s
- types
- externs
- template code
- function prototypes

The cause of your problem is likely that you have included a full function definition in your H file, and so, when you compile your A and B implementation files (they should be called *implementation files* if you're compiling them; alternatively, you can think about moving function definitions from those header files into separate implementation files, and only compiling *those* implementation files), the function is being compiled into both AO and BO object files. That is why linking fails; the functions are multiply defined at link-time.

To solve the problem, you need to move any function definitions that you have in the H header file into a separate implementation file. Since H does not appear to be tied to any single implementation file that you already have (I say this because it appears to be a dependency of both A and B), it probably makes most sense to move those function definitions into a new H.cpp implementation file. As part of your build process, you will then have to build H.cpp, and link that into the final executable at link-time.

Comment: You absolutely _do_ compile header files. You just don't do so as units.

Comment: So, if I link HO while compiling to AO from A.cpp , and then link it while compiling to BO from B.cpp, and then a third time link it when compiling M(.exe) from M.cpp, this issue cannot occur? That means, HO does not somehow get "baked in" into any of the other object files when linking it for compiling them?

Comment: Ack, you're technically correct @LightnessRacesinOrbit. But you know what I meant; you don't compile header files *by themselves*; their code only gets included in translation units via `#include`s, and the whole thing then gets compiled.

Comment: @lotolmencre, there is no linking when you're building an object file. When compiling AO from A.cpp (and same with BO from B.cpp), you don't need the HO function definitions *at all*. All you need at compile-time is the header content (see the list in my answer). Only at the end of the whole build process, after you've compiled HO, AO, and BO (in *any* order; the object files do *not* depend on one another), do you then link M.exe, and only at that time do you need to reference all of HO, AO, and BO to link their function definitions into the final executable M.exe.

Comment: @bgoldst you do compile header files by themself, when using *precompiled headers*

Comment: @MattMcNabb, header precompilation is a different process, with a different output, from translation unit compilation, and is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Yes of course I know what you meant but don't forget you're teaching! The OP wouldn't have known what you meant. You're being imprecise and contrary to what the pedantry police like to make up, that _does_ matter.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember the header guards in your header files, otherwise you end up with this issue.

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H_INC
#define MY_HEADER_H_INC

/* Put Header Code Here */

#endif // MY_HEADER_H_INC
```

You end up including the same file multiple times, because as you stated you have header H included in both then you include each. This sounds like the most likely cause.

Comment: header guards won't help with multiple files each including the same header only once

Comment: This would be more likely if it were a class, not functions, with the error.

Comment: This is not the problem. Include guards only protect against multiple inclusions of the same source file into the same translation unit. The OP is compiling multiple translation units, thus the function definitions in the H header file will be multiply defined at link-time regardless whether H included an include guard.

Comment: @chris How So? I'm not sure how having function prototypes is any different than having a class in a header.

Comment: @HSchmale, I mean class definitions vs. function definitions. C++ allows multiple identical class definitions across translation units, but not within the same translation unit. Include guards prevent the latter. Multiple function definitions are not allowed across translation units, so include guards do not help there.

Comment: @chris I thought you meant prototypes. If I end up declaring and **Implementing** a function in a header I end up declaring it `static` or `inline`, so I have never really come across such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you should separate declarations from implementation in order to avoid redefinitions (as in the situation you have described). Put the declarations into a header file filename.h, with some sort of include guard inside (either #def-based or #pragma once); put your definitions in filename.cpp, which includes the header via #include "filename.h". When you compile, you only compile .cpp files; do not try to compile headers (unless you need a precompiled header, which you probably do not).